# Extract username from url with regex

Tags: java, regex

I am extracting usernames from urls using `^(?:https?://)?(?:www.)?(?:website.com)?/?([^/\s]+)`. This method will return "username?lang=en". How can i remove the "?lang=en" from the end ?

Comment: Replace `([^/\s]+)` with `([^/\s?#]+)`. Also, escape the literal dots in the pattern.

Comment: Why not use `URL` to parse your URL…?!

Comment: Thank you Wiktor :) I have not used regex alot so alot of this is learning and playing around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```java
^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:website\.com)?/?([^/\s?#]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TjbfUz/1/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:https?://)?` - an optional occurrence of `http://` or `https://`
- `(?:www\.)?` - an optional occurrence of `www.` (note that the literal dot must be escaped)
- `(?:website\.com)?` - an optional occurrence of `website.com`
- `/?` - an optional `/` char
- `([^/\s?#]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `/`, whitespace, `?` and `#` chars.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is looking for this, you can use:

```
^(?:(?:https?)?(?:\:\/\/)?)?(?:\w*\.)?(?:\w+)?.(?:\w+)\/(\w+)$
```

it will match subdomains as well:

```
https://website.com/username
http://website.com/username
https://www.website.com/username
http://website.com/username
www.website.com/username
```